# PHPUnit coverage test elseif error

Tags: phpunit, test-coverage

ok, so I'm taking a look at a code, and I'm doing a phpunit coverage test. In said test, I only get 2 lines that aren't working appropriately:

```
private function getEarliestDateOrNull($snapshotDate = null, $preexistingEpisodeDate = null)
{
    $date = null;

    if ($snapshotDate instanceof DateTime && $preexistingEpisodeDate instanceof DateTime) {
        $date = $snapshotDate < $preexistingEpisodeDate ? $snapshotDate : $preexistingEpisodeDate;
    } elseif ($snapshotDate instanceof DateTime) {
        $date = $snapshotDate;
    } elseif ($preexistingEpisodeDate instanceof DateTime) {
        $date = $preexistingEpisodeDate;
    }

    return ($date instanceof DateTime) ? $date->format('m/d/Y') : null;
}
```

The problem is within my getEarliestDateorNull, both elseif statements are the only ones that the test for some reason does not read. Is there a way to change them from an elseif statements? I mean to say, if there could be an SWITCH implementation. The test runs in php 7.

Comment: You say you have two lines that are not working appropriately, yet you paste 103 lines...

Comment: @JoeC ok, I've modified it. I'd very much appreciate to know what the error is. How can I implement an alternative to both elseif statements?

Comment: I'm also having this issue with elseif being covered with PHPUnit 5.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, if you set it to `else if` not `elseif` it should work :)

Comment: yeah, I tried switching it, and it worked! 
Although I have to wonder why it didn't recognize it? and if I switch from php 7 to php 5.6 it should work on both versions, right?

Comment: hey Andy! I have a follow up question, when I run the code... since it enters the if statement, it should only read either the first if, and ignore the second else if, or otherwise read the second else if and ignore the first if and second else if, right? In the code coverage test, it reads ALL 3 statements. Do you know what could be implemented in order to just pick ONE of the 3 statements? Thanks!